# Sharing a linked list using pipe in c

Tags: c, linked-list, pipe

I have the following question: how can I send a linked list using pipe (IPC) in c so that the parent doesn't lose the list data?
Because when I go to try to read the linked list in the parent process the data isn't shown, it's like the list wasn't shared.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct Lista {
  char word[256];
  int occurrence, lines[1000];
  struct Lista *next;
};

struct Lista *node;

void inserirNaLista(char *word, int *lines, int occurrence) {
  struct Lista *link = (struct Lista *)malloc(sizeof(struct Lista));
  strcpy(link->word, word);
  link->occurrence = occurrence;
  int size = sizeof(lines) / sizeof(lines[0]);
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (lines[i] > 0) link->lines[i] = lines[i];
  }
  link->next = node;
  node = link;
}

struct Lista *readPipeResult(int pipe[]) {
  struct Lista *buffer;
  read(pipe[0], &buffer, sizeof(struct Lista *));
  return buffer;
}

void writePipeResult(int pipe[]) {
  write(pipe[1], &node, sizeof(struct Lista *));
}

void childProcess(int pipe[]) {
  int resp;
  int lines[4] = {1, 3, 9, 10};
  node = NULL;
  inserirNaLista("poiasasdasd", lines, 20);
  inserirNaLista("qwerty", lines, 5);
  inserirNaLista("lolololol", lines, 10);
  while (node != NULL) {
    printf("%s - %d\n", node->word, node->occurrence);
    node = node->next;
  }
  writePipeResult(pipe);
  exit(resp);
}

void parentProcess(int pipe[]) {
  struct Lista *buffer = readPipeResult(pipe);

  printf("\nI passed here\n");
  while (buffer != NULL) {
    printf("%s - %d\n", buffer->word, buffer->occurrence);
    buffer = buffer->next;
  }
}

int main() {
  int pipe[2], status;

  pid_t pid = fork();

  if (pid < 0) {
    printf("An error occurred");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  } else if (pid == 0) {
    childProcess(pipe);
  } else {
    wait(&status);
    if (status == EXIT_FAILURE) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    parentProcess(pipe);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

If you can show me an example of how this could be done, I would appreciate it.

Comment: We don't just do full worked solutions on demand. You'll have to break the task up into smaller steps, attempt to code one step at a time and then come back to show the code and ask about the specific step you get stuck on. For example, do you know how to create a pipe, fork a process, write to a pipe, read from a pipe, etc?. Without knowing what you can or can't do already we cannot answer the question short of doing the whole thing for you.

Comment: A linked list is an in-memory data structure.  A pipe is an inter-process communications medium.  You're not going to send a linked list through a pipe.  It's going to be more like: walk the linked list on the sending end to extract the data and send it through the pipe, and on the receiving end, receive the data from the pipe, and construct a new linked list.

Comment: I updated the question adding my code @kaylum and I made a small change to the struct

Comment: You don't seem to be creating the pipe anywhere. Did you maybe forget to call [`pipe`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html)?

Comment: `write(pipe[1], &node, sizeof(struct Lista *));` That's never going to work. Pointers/addresses are only valid within a process. They cannot be used outside the process. You need to do data serialisation.

Comment: If you're sharing a list over a pipe, simply send the data in the sequence of the list (without the pointers, or completely ignoring the pointers in the receiving process).  The pointers in one process are irrelevant in the other — or will most likely cause crashes.

Comment: @kaylum how could I serialize the data in this case? if possible can you show me an example?

Comment: What is the point of the line `write(pipe[1], &node, sizeof(struct Lista *));`? When that line is executed, `node` will always have the value `NULL`, so you are only sending bytes with the value `0` over the pipe.

Comment: Send the data inside the node (not including the next pointer). Send it in a pre-agreed order, e.g. in-order traversal. Then on the other side reconstruct each node and its links as the data arrives.

Comment: @MatheusWilliam: In order to serialize the data, you could for example do the following: You could start with the first node of the linked list and write the 256 characters of `word` to the pipe, followed by the 4 bytes of `occurrence`, followed by the 1000 characters of `lines`. DO NOT write the `next` member of the linked list node to the pipe, as that memory address is useless to the other process. After sending the data of the first node, you can start sending the data of the second node.